# Grepping dates that do not satisfy year-pattern YYYY-01-01

Tags: regex, grep

I need to anonymize birth dates in metadata files and redact the month and day fields, e.g., I need to convert `1976-05-25` into `1976-01-01`.  For backup purposes, I first need to test whether a file contains a non-redacted birth date.  I ususally use grep for these tests, like this

```
if grep -E PATTERN $file > /dev/null; then cp $file /backups/; fi
```

However, I struggle to find a nice and elegant pattern for this task.  I've tried

```
grep -E '([12][09][0-9][0-9])-(^(01))-(^(01))'
```

but it does not accept, e.g., `2001-10-11` or any other date.

I could of course also do something along the lines of

```
([12][09][0-9][0-9]-0[0-9]-0[^1]|[12][09][0-9][0-9]-0[0-9]-1[0-9]|...)
```

but this is too complicated and error prone.

Of course, I do not want it to accept dates of the form `YYYY-01-01` to avoid a double-backup.

What is a simple (read: elegant) way to grep these dates in a single pattern?

Comment: What happens if someone's birthday is `1976-01-01`?

Comment: @l'L'l then it will be indistinguishable from another birthday in the same year, and therefore secure.

Comment: @I'L'I: shall not be accepted (sorry, edited that in later)

Comment: Why not `grep -v` (`-v` for invert match)?

Comment: @nhahtdh: the metadata file is actually a multi-line xml file, where one of the lines contains a `<birthdate>YYYY-MM-DD<birthdate>` line - `grep -v` would be true for all of the other lines.

Comment: @AlexanderLanger: You can make it go through 2 rounds of grep by piping: first round takes the line with date, second round remove all 01-01.

Comment: @Alex, at some point, with all these complexities being added, you will realise that `grep` is not the best tool for the job. The instant XML comes into the picture, you should probably start looking at a XML processing tool of some description. There are too many variations for `grep` to elegantly handle.

Comment: yes, that's true, of course.  I was too much focused on a single pattern, because I was curious about a single-pattern solution :)

Comment: paxdiablo: that's probably overkill, the task is actually quite simple. however, I have not added these additional tasks to my question, so I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would probably just back it up regardless of content but that's because I have more disk space than time to worry about things like this :-)

However, *one* approach could be to look at it in reverse. Count the lines in the full file then count the lines containing just the pattern with `-01-01`.

If they're the same then all the dates are of the `-01-01` variety and no backup is needed.

Just be aware you need to watch out if there are *multiple* dates per line but, in that case, you could use other filters to get just the data you're interested in.

As an example, consider the file `infile`:

```
2009-01-01 A very good year
2010-02-01 A moderately good year
2011-01-01 A better year
2012-12-31 Not so good
2013-01-01 Back to normal
```

You can detect dates at the start of the line of the format you want and count them, comparing that to the full file:

```
if [[ $(wc -l <infile) -ne $(grep -E '^[0-9]{4}-01-01' infile | wc -l) ]]
then
    echo File needs backing up
fi
```

---

One other possibility would be to *exclude* the `01-01` patterns with the `-v` option:

```
pax> grep -Ev '[0-9]{4}-01-01' infile
2010-02-01 A moderately good year
2012-12-31 Not so good
```

This is relatively easy to detect from an `if` statement:

```
if [[ ! -z "$(grep -Ev '^[0-9]{4}-01-01' infile)" ]] ; then
    echo File needs backing up
fi
```

Comment: It's actually that the modified/redacted files are then automatically transferred to a central server based on the last modification date, so I don't want to edit them if not necessary.

Comment: The reverse-idea would probably work, that's a great idea.  However, for educational reasons I'm nevertheless interested in actual patterns that match such dates, too :-)

Comment: @Alex, added a regex for that case but it's pretty ugly compared to the other solution. Still, if you really _want_ to do it that way, you can use it.

Comment: the `wc` test will work for my case, thanks a lot.  I'm leaving the question open for now due to the pattern part of the question.

Comment: accepting now since it is in fact a nice way to do that with grep.  I will open another question for a single regex.