# Regex for dates that do not satisfy year-pattern YYYY-01-01

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I had a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929586/grepping-dates-that-do-not-satisfy-year-pattern-yyyy-01-01), which was successfully answered using multiple piped shell commands.  However, a question that arose from my original question is:

**What is the most elegant regular expression (POSIX or Extended Regular) for birthyear-dates between 1900 and 2XXX that do NOT satisfy `YYYY-01-01`**

I can come up with something along the lines of

```
(19|2[01])[0-9][0-9]-(1[012]-[0-9][0-9]|0[^1]-[0-9][0-9]|01-[123][0-9]|01-0[^1])
```

i.e., accept all years starting with 19, 20, or 21 and then allow every month >= 10 and all months > 01 with arbitrary day, and then finally all days in month `01` that are not `01`, but this is clearly not elegant.  It does, however, mimic the way an FTA would accept the word.

Is it possible to shorten this regex, possibly using extended regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? Would this be considered as elegant?? :P

`(19\d{2}|2\d{3})-((?!01-01)\d{2}-\d{2}| )`

**Update**:

`(19\d{2}|2\d{3})-(?!01-01)\d{2}-\d{2}`

Try it [here](http://regex101.com/r/hG2iZ7/5)!

Comment: Would be very elegant, but it does not seem to match `1974-01-17` (and `2001-18-01` only partially).

Comment: Oops. Sorry, my bad. I forgot that `01-01` needs to be together. I've updated the answer. You can also check [here](http://regex101.com/r/hG2iZ7/2)

Comment: I like the idea, but you haven't even validated that it's a date! For instance, `1942-whatever` would match. And why have the alternation on the end to match a space?

Comment: Ah..i took a shortcut to match anything. It's not an alternation by the way. It's conditional check `((Condition)Yes|No)`. For more info, see [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html). I'm putting a space there because you do not wanna match `01-01`. See updated [example](http://regex101.com/r/hG2iZ7/4).

Comment: No, it's an alternation with a negative lookahead inside. If you want the lookahead to be a condition, you need a question mark inside the paren: `(?(cond)Yes|No)`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, Brian. It was a typo and i actually intended to use `(?(cond)yes|no)` but i missed the `?`. I just realized that `(19\d{2}|2\d{3})-(?!01-01)\d{2}-\d{2}` will suffice.

Comment: I agree. The only thing left depends on how exact he wants to be with day and month values. It can be ugly if you want only REAL dates, but something like this gets it 95% there: `(0[1-9]|1[012])` for month, `(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` for day.

Comment: the solution is perfectly fine, no need to restrict the date pattern further.  Wow, I'm impressed, I was not even aware that you can do such conditional lookaheads.  That's a very nice solution, well done!